# Custom memcpy with void pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I was trying to implement a memcpy function using void pointer.

my buf1 is "apple" and buf2 is "banana".
I expected "banana" and "banana" for the output however I got a segmentation fault at 
    *s1_charPtr++ = *s2_charPtr++;

I tried to debug it, but GDB does not give me a useful information.

I want to keep these rules:

1. I want to keep the type of function and its argument.
2. Use pointer to dereference casted argument.

What have I done wrong? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void* memcpy(void* s1, const void* s2, unsigned n){

    char* s1_charPtr = static_cast<char*>(s1);
    const char* s2_charPtr = static_cast<const char*>(s2);

    int i = 0;
    while(i < n){
        *s1_charPtr++ = *s2_charPtr++;
        i++;
    }
}

int main(){
    char* buf1 = new char[10];
    const char* buf2 = new char[10];
    buf1 = "apple";
    buf2 = "banana";

    memcpy(buf1, buf2, 5);
    cout << buf1 << "\n" << buf2 << endl;

    delete[] buf1;
    delete[] buf2;
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question: the parameter `n` is unsigned, yet you use a signed counter `i`. You should declare `i` the same as `n`. Even better, declare both of them as type `size_t` as in standard `memcpy`.

Comment: WTH should be customized with `memcpy`??? Let's see, either bad question or misachievement of concepts ...

Comment: Your function signature says it returns a `void*` but there's no `return` statement. Turn up your compiler warning level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is these assignments:

```
buf1 = "apple";
buf2 = "banana";
```

After this, `buf1` and `buf2` no longer point to the buffers you allocated with `new` earlier, they point to these literal strings. Literal strings are constant, so when you try to modify `"apple"` you get a fault.

You should do:

```
strcpy(buf1, "apple");
strcpy(buf2, "banana");
```

This is why you should pay attention to compiler warnings:

```
testmemcpy.cpp:18: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
```

Comment: I see your point. By the way, is there a way to put two strings into the buffer that I created earlier?

Comment: *without using strcpy*

Comment: When I apply your code, the compiler complains since buf2 is const char*, not char*.

Comment: @Peter: Well, you shouldn't be making it const if you plan to write to it later.

Comment: I doubt there's a good alternative to strcpy or strncpy. If you're allergic to string.h you can do this: const char* silly = "apple";for (int i = 0;i < 5; ++i){buf1[i] = silly[i];}

Comment: To initialize array, you may use: `const char buf2[10] = "banana"`. If you want for allocated memory, you need C++11 and then you may use `const char* buf2 = new char[10] {'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', '\0'};`.

Comment: @Peter Without using `strcpy`? You could use `memcpy` :)

Comment: @user3109672: You forget to copy leading `'\0'`. range should be `[0; 1 + strlen("apple")]` so `[0; 1 + 5]`.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to believe that `buf1 = "apple";` copies the string literal into the buffer you allocated earlier. This is not the case. Instead, `buf1` is made to point to the location of the string literal in memory, and the buffer you've allocated earlier is simply leaked.

You then attempt to write to the memory where the string literal is located. This exhibits undefined behavior. Practically speaking, many compilers (GCC included) place string literals into a memory segment marked read-only - hence segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
char* buf1 = new char[10];
const char* buf2 = new char[10];
buf1 = "apple";
buf2 = "banana";
```

buf1 and buf2:they are pointers,not strings.'buf1 = "apple" 'such behavior redirect the pointer to the head of the const string "apple".

And finally you delete these pointers not pointing to the memory position you just alloced,obviosly this will cause memory leaks.

use 'strcpy' please.